# natbib not expanding authors for initial in-text citation

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I'm trying to cite a paper with multiple authors using APA standard using `natbib`.

For the initial citation, all authors should be listed, then for subsequent references it should start to use `et al`. I can't get this working, and the first instance of a reference appears as below:

[image: unexpanded author citation]

I've tried using both `\citep{}` and `\citep*{}`, neither expand the authors. Here's the entry as it appears in the bib file:

```
@article{Goodrich2009,
  year = {2009},
  month = dec,
  publisher = {American Medical Association ({AMA})},
  volume = {163},
  number = {12},
  author = {Samantha A. Goodrich and Tiffany A. Pempek and Sandra L. Calvert},
  title = {Formal Production Features of Infant and Toddler {DVDs}},
  journal = {Archives of Pediatrics {\&} Adolescent Medicine}
}
```

I'm using `apalike` as the bibliography style, but the problem still persists when using `apa`.

Comment: Can you please add a small example of a document?

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style is one of the "original" bibliography style files, created around the time BibTeX was created. I.e., it dates back to the early 1980s and it hasn't been changed substantially since then. Moreover, the `apalike` bib style predates the `natbib` package by more than a decade. As such, `apalike` is not set up to work with natbib's `longnamesfirst` option. As suggested in [@Denis's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529124/5001), you're better off switching to the `apacite` bib style and eponymous citation management package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apacite`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Goodrich2009,
  year = {2009},
  month = dec,
  publisher = {American Medical Association ({AMA})},
  volume = {163},
  number = {12},
  author = {Samantha A. Goodrich and Tiffany A. Pempek and Sandra L. Calvert},
  title = {Formal Production Features of Infant and Toddler {DVDs}},
  journal = {Archives of Pediatrics {\&} Adolescent Medicine}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Dummy text here \citep{Goodrich2009}

\citet{Goodrich2009}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]

Comment: Don't load both `apacite` and `natbib`. (Hint: It suffices to load `apacite` with the option `natbibapa`.)

Comment: @Mico Right! I am updating the anwser.